# Binding Click to select widget in Admin Panel

Tags: magento2, module, admin

Has any of you successfully binded `click` to `admin panel select widget`? Or have idea how to?

So far I've successfully binded `click` on `admin panel button widget` (I've added code in its `action` method), but, AFAIK, `select widget` does not have `action` method....

EDIT:
Here is my select definition from xml:

```
<field name="country">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Company\StoreLocator\Model\Config\Source\ListCountry</item>
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Country</item>
        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">storelocator</item>
        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">3</item>
        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">country</item>
        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Company_StoreLocator/js/fetchStates</item>
        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>
```

fetchStates.js is default file copied from module-ui/.../web/js/form/element/select.js . I've tried to add listeners to initializers, but failed...

Answer (score 0):

After all, my solution is just to check for component load with setInterval, checking length of designated widget jQuery selector, and carrying all logic after satisfying statement.

```
var that = this;
this.checkExist = setInterval(function() {
    if ($('.admin__control-select[name="country"]').length) {
        that.domReadyInits();
        clearInterval(that.checkExist);
    }
}, 200);
```